Error Azure Device Update when handler is microsoft/script:1
I'm trying to make an update using Azure Device Update on ubuntu 22.04. When my update is of type apt (microsoft/apt:1) it works fine.
But when I try to run a script (microsoft/script:1) i'm getting error from ADU: 810549253 (0x30500005).
ADUC_ERC_SCRIPT_HANDLER_MISSING_SCRIPTFILENAME_PROPERTY MAKE_ADUC_EXTENDEDRESULTCODE_FOR_COMPONENT_ADUC_CONTENT_HANDLER_SCRIPT(5)
List of errors: result.h
Here the script that I want to run:
script_test.sh:

#!/bin/bash

# Create a directory
mkdir -p /home/azureuser/this_was_create_by_adu

# Create a text file with specified content inside the directory
echo "this file was generated by adu" > /home/azureuser/this_was_create_by_adu/generated_file.txt

# Confirmation message
echo "Directory and file have been created successfully."

The import manifest:
script_test.importmanifest.json:
{
  "updateId": {
    "name": "script",
    "provider": "me",
    "version": "7.0.0"
  },
  "compatibility": [
    {
      "manufacturer": "hp",
      "model": "elite"
    }
  ],
  "createdDateTime": "2024-10-23T09:33:11Z",
  "files": [
    {
      "filename": "script_test.sh",
      "hashes": {
        "sha256": "lHKs3UsbWJAE3Svz3KwPCWibEofSPisKfB2rsbyIM4E="
      },
      "sizeInBytes": 328
    }
  ],
  "instructions": {
    "steps": [
      {
        "files": [
          "script_test.sh"
        ],
        "handler": "microsoft/script:1",
        "handlerProperties": {
        "installedCriteria": "1.0",
        },
        "type": "inline"
      }
    ]
  },
  "manifestVersion": "5.0"
}

The log error:
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8793Z 5742[7981] [I] Try to load a handler for current update manifest version 5 (handler: 'microsoft/update-manifest:5') [GetUpdateManifestHandler:114]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8793Z 5742[7981] [I] Loading handler for 'microsoft/update-manifest:5'. [LoadUpdateContentHandlerExtension:208]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8794Z 5742[7981] [I] Loading extension 'microsoft/update-manifest:5'. Reg file : /var/lib/adu/extensions/update_content_handlers/microsoft_update-manifest_5/content_handler.json [LoadExtensionLibrary:85]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8794Z 5742[7981] [D] Determining contract version for 'microsoft/update-manifest:5'. [LoadUpdateContentHandlerExtension:303]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8794Z 5742[7981] [D] Got 1.0 contract version for 'microsoft/update-manifest:5' handler [LoadUpdateContentHandlerExtension:331]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8794Z 5742[7981] [D] Caching new handler for 'microsoft/update-manifest:5'. [LoadUpdateContentHandlerExtension:340]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8797Z 5742[7981] [I] Action 'Download' complete. Result: 0 (failed), 810549253 (0x30500005) [ADUC_Workflow_WorkCompletionCallback:890]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8797Z 5742[7981] [I] WorkCompletionCallback: Download failed. Going to state Failed [ADUC_Workflow_WorkCompletionCallback:1016]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8797Z 5742[7981] [I] Setting UpdateState to Failed [ADUC_Workflow_SetUpdateStateHelper:1088]
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8797Z 5742[7981] [D] [ADUC_D2C_Message_SendAsync:526] ==== MULTI-LINE LOG BEGIN ====
Queueing message (t:0, c:0x64006e50, m:{"deviceUpdate":{"__t":"c","agent":{"lastInstallResult":{"stepResults":{"step_0":{"resultCode":0,"extendedResultCodes":"00000000","resultDetails":null}},"resultCode":0,"extendedResultCodes":"30500005,A0000FFF","resultDetails":""},"state":255,"workflow":{"action":3,"id":"aebe0066-67ba-4d78-a247-2656d91dd7c8"}}}})2024-11-05T15:39:52.8797Z 5742[7981] [D] [ADUC_D2C_Message_SendAsync:526] ==== MULTI-LINE LOG END ====
2024-11-05T15:39:52.8815Z 5742[7981] [I] Workflow is Complete. [ADUC_Workflow_AutoTransitionWorkflow:758]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2803Z 5742[5742] [D] context:0xb6b015a0 [DefaultIoTHubSendReportedStateCompletedCallback:205]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2803Z 5742[5742] [D] D2C message processed successfully (t:0, r:0, content:0xb8465da0 ) [DefaultIoTHubSendReportedStateCompletedCallback:233]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2803Z 5742[5742] [D] Send message completed (status:3) [OnUpdateResultD2CMessageCompleted:64]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2804Z 5742[5742] [D] context:0xb6b01640 [DefaultIoTHubSendReportedStateCompletedCallback:205]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2804Z 5742[5742] [D] D2C message processed successfully (t:1, r:0, content:0xb843b8c0 ) [DefaultIoTHubSendReportedStateCompletedCallback:233]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2804Z 5742[5742] [D] Send message completed (status:3) [OnUpdateResultD2CMessageCompleted:64]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2804Z 5742[5742] [D] Sending D2C message (t:0, retries:0). [ProcessMessage:390]
2024-11-05T15:39:53.2804Z 5742[5742] [D] [ADUC_D2C_Default_Message_Transport_Function:580] ==== MULTI-LINE LOG BEGIN ====
Sending D2C message:
{"deviceUpdate":{"__t":"c","agent":{"lastInstallResult":{"stepResults":{"step_0":{"resultCode":0,"extendedResultCodes":"00000000","resultDetails":null}},"resultCode":0,"extendedResultCodes":"30500005,A0000FFF","resultDetails":""},"state":255,"workflow":{"action":3,"id":"aebe0066-67ba-4d78-a247-2656d91dd7c8"}}}}2024-11-05T15:39:53.2804Z 5742[5742] [D] [ADUC_D2C_Default_Message_Transport_Function:580] ==== MULTI-LINE LOG END ====

please the link/doc you followed in the above question

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/import-schema

After restarting the Virtual Machine that I was using for testing, I encountered a different error:
"The install script doesn't create a result file '/var/lib/adu/downloads/aebe0066-67ba-4d78-a247-2656d91dd7c8/action_download_aduc_result.json'."
According to the responses on the issue I opened on GitHub, I noticed that I wasn't writing the result to the result file, which is mandatory
https://github.com/Azure/iot-hub-device-update/issues/667.
Following the documentation and the example script I rewrote the script and the import manifest and it worked properly:
script_test.importmanifest.json:
{
  "compatibility": [
    {
      "manufacturer": "hp",
      "model": "elite"
    }
  ],
  "createdDateTime": "2024-11-15T14:30:05Z",
  "files": [
    {
      "filename": "script_test.sh",
      "hashes": {
        "sha256": "WRgOrX+fgPECHrmEX1i6XmnghiYwe+4PGPv0Tjm2vpQ="
      },
      "sizeInBytes": 5902
    }
  ],
  "instructions": {
    "steps": [
      {
        "files": [
          "script_test.sh"
        ],
        "handler": "microsoft/script:1",
        "handlerProperties": {
          "arguments": "",
          "scriptFileName": "script_test.sh",
                    "installedCriteria": "1.0"
        },
        "type": "inline"
      }
    ]
  },
  "manifestVersion": "5.0",
  "updateId": {
    "name": "scriptupdate",
    "provider": "me",
    "version": "51.0.0"
  }
}

script_test.sh
#!/bin/bash

# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
# Licensed under the MIT License.

# Ensure that getopt starts from first option if ". <script.sh>" was used.
OPTIND=1

# Ensure we don't end the user's terminal session if invoked from source (".").
if [[ $0 != "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]]; then
    ret='return'
else
    ret='exit'
fi

# Output formatting.

# Log level: 0=debug, 1=info, 2=warning, 3=error, 4=none
log_level=1

warn() { echo -e "\033[1;33mWarning:\033[0m $*" >&2; }

error() { echo -e "\033[1;31mError:\033[0m $*" >&2; }

header() { echo -e "\e[4m\e[1m\e[1;32m$*\e[0m"; }

bullet() { echo -e "\e[1;34m*\e[0m $*"; }

# Log debug prefix - blue
log_debug_pref="\033[1;30m[D]\033[0m"

# Log info prefix - blue
log_info_pref="\033[1;34m[I]\033[0m"

# Log warning prefix - yellow
log_warn_pref="\033[1;33m[W]\033[0m"

# Log error prefix - red
log_error_pref="\033[1;31m[E]\033[0m"

#
# Install poicy
#
#install_error_policy="abort"
#install_reboot_policy="none"

# component_props will contain a map of property.
declare -A component_props

#
# Files and Folders information
#
workfolder=
output_file=
log_file=
result_file=

#
# Device Update specific arguments
#
do_install_action=

#
# Remaining aguments and parameters
#
PARAMS=

#
# Output, Logs, and Result helper functions.
#
_timestamp=

update_timestamp() {
    # See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html
    _timestamp="$(date +'%Y/%m/%d:%H%M%S')"
}

log_debug() {
    if [ $log_level -gt 0 ]; then
        return
    fi
    log "$log_debug_pref" "$@"
}

log_info() {
    if [ $log_level -gt 1 ]; then
        return
    fi
    log "$log_info_pref" "$@"
}

log_warn() {
    if [ $log_level -gt 2 ]; then
        return
    fi
    log "$log_warn_pref" "$@"
}

log_error() {
    if [ $log_level -gt 3 ]; then
        return
    fi
    log "$log_error_pref" "$@"
}

log() {
    update_timestamp
    if [ -z "$log_file" ]; then
        echo -e "[$_timestamp]" "$@" >&1
    else
        echo "[$_timestamp]" "$@" >> "$log_file"
    fi
}

output() {
    update_timestamp
    if [ -z "$output_file" ]; then
        echo "[$_timestamp]" "$@" >&1
    else
        echo "[$_timestamp]" "$@" >> "$output_file"
    fi
}

#
# Write result json string to result file.
#
result() {
    # NOTE: don't insert timestamp in result file.
    if [ -z "$result_file" ]; then
        echo "$@" >&1
    else
        echo "$@" > "$result_file"
    fi
}

log "Log begin:"
output "Output begin:"

#
# Parsing arguments
#
while [[ $1 != "" ]]; do
    case $1 in

    #
    # Component-related arguments.
    #
    # Following arguments and parameters will be populated by the Script Step Handler.
    #

    #
    # Device Update specific arguments.
    #
    --action-install)
        shift
        log_info "Will runscript as 'installer' script."
        do_install_action=yes
        ;;

    #
    # Update artifacts
    #

    --work-folder)
        shift
        if [[ -z $1 || $1 == -* ]]; then
            error "--work-folder parameter is mandatory."
            $ret 1
        fi
        workfolder="$1"
        echo "Workfolder: $workfolder"
        shift
        ;;

    #
    # Output-related arguments.
    #
    # --out-file <file_path>, --result-file <file_path>, --log-file <file_path>
    #
    --output-file)
        shift
        if [[ -z $1 || $1 == -* ]]; then
            error "--out-file parameter is mandatory."
            $ret 1
        fi
        output_file="$1"

        #
        #Create output file path.
        #
        # Delete existing log.
        rm -f -r "$output_file"
        # Create dir(s) recursively (include filename, well remove it in the following line...).
        mkdir -p "$output_file"
        shift
        ;;

    --result-file)
        shift
        if [[ -z $1 || $1 == -* ]]; then
            error "--result-file parameter is mandatory."
            $ret 1
        fi
        result_file="$1"
        #
        #Create result file path.
        #
        # Delete existing log.
        rm -f -r "$result_file"
        # Create dir(s) recursively (include filename, well remove it in the following line...).
        touch "$result_file"
        shift
        ;;

    --log-file)
        shift
        if [[ -z $1 || $1 == -* ]]; then
            error "--log-file parameter is mandatory."
            $ret 1
        fi
        log_file="$1"
        shift
        ;;
    --log-level)
        shift
        if [[ -z $1 || $1 == -* ]]; then
            error "--log-level parameter is mandatory."
            $ret 1
        fi
        log_level=$1
        shift
        ;;

    -h | --help)
        print_help
        $ret 0
        ;;

    *) # preserve positional arguments
        PARAMS="$PARAMS $1"
        shift
        ;;
    esac
done

#
# Main
#

resultCode=0
extendedResultCode=1
resultDetails=""

# Update apt-get
sudo apt-get update

# Install cowsay
sudo apt-get install cowsay

# Create a directory
mkdir -p /home/azureuser/this_was_create_by_adu

# Create a text file with specified content inside the directory
echo "this file was generated by adu on $(TZ='UTC-1' date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z')" > /home/azureuser/this_was_create_by_adu/generated_file.txt

# Confirmation message
if [ -d "/home/azureuser/this_was_create_by_adu" ] && [ -f "/home/azureuser/this_was_create_by_adu/generated_file.txt" ]; then
    log_info "Both directory and file exist."
    resultCode=600
    extendedResultCode=0
    resultDetails="folder and file created"
    ret_val=0
else
    log_info "Either the directory or file does not exist."
    resultDetails="Folder and/or file have been not created"
    exit 1
fi

# Prepare ADUC_Result json.
aduc_result_json="{\"resultCode\":$resultCode, \"extendedResultCode\":$extendedResultCode,\"resultDetails\":\"$resultDetails\"}"

# Show output.
output "Result:" "$aduc_result_json"

# Write ADUC_Result to result file.

result "$aduc_result_json"

exit 0


I tried your code and received the same error while running the updates. There is an issue with the C  and script_test.sh code, so I tried an alternative method using PowerShell to update the device.
I used this doc to help with the process.
Below code is to the import manifest   in a single payload file of contoso.toaster.1.0.importmanifest.json
Import-Module ./AduUpdate.psm1
$file = './README.md'
$updateId = New-AduUpdateId -Provider Contoso -Name Toaster -Version 1.0
$compat = New-AduUpdateCompatibility -Properties @{ manufacturer = 'Contoso'; model = 'Toaster' }
$installStep = New-AduInstallationStep -Handler 'microsoft/swupdate:1'-HandlerProperties @{ installedCriteria = '1.0' } -Files $file
$update = New-AduImportManifest -UpdateId $updateId -Compatibility $compat -InstallationSteps $installStep
$update | Out-File ./contoso.toaster.1.0.importmanifest.json -Encoding utf8



This creates a contoso.toaster.1.0.importmanifest.json file. You can use the following bash command to update the device with a single payload file to be installed:
./create-adu-import-manifest.sh -p 'Contoso' -n 'Toaster' -v '1.0' -c 'manufacturer:Contoso' -c 'model:Toaster' -h 'microsoft/swupdate:1' -r 'installedCriteria:1.0' ./README.md > ./contoso.toaster.1.0.importmanifest.json



Next step  is we need to  create an Azure storage account and a container in Azure.
Create a Device Update for IoT Hub, link the Azure IoT instances, and assign the IoT Hub Data Contributor role to IoT.
Go to IoT >> Updates and click on "Import New Update."

For the above image select the storage and container, then upload the files contoso.toaster.1.0.importmanifest.json and README.txt as shown below:

After some time, check the updates:

Upadated:
For using microsoft/script:1 :
./create-adu-import-manifest.sh \
  -p 'Contoso' \
  -n 'Toaster' \
  -v '1.0' \
  -c 'manufacturer:Contoso' \
  -c 'model:Toaster' \
  -h 'microsoft/script:1' \
  -r 'installedCriteria:1.0' \
  ./README.md > ./contoso.toaster.1.0.importmanifest.json


In this specific case, we need to use the handler "microsoft/script:1" instead of "microsoft/swupdate:1.". Swupdate is image-based not script-base.

As per offical this
documention Use --step: it updates handler on the device (for example, microsoft/script:1, microsoft/swupdate:1, or microsoft/apt:1) and its associated.

Upadted with microsoft/script:1
